# Top Answers, anyone transferring Q&A?

Tags: discussion

I just became aware of https://topanswers.xyz/databases via a conversation on a sister SE site.  I see several familiar names over there.  I have not really looked around much, it is different but it has the potential to fully replace DBA.SE for my needs.

Is anyone actively moving any content from here to there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are quite a few active members, but the site is still officially in "beta" status.  Questions are migrated there manually, by select users.

If you want, go [here](https://topanswers.xyz/meta?room=1), create an account, and ask Jack if he'll let you migrate your questions into /databases.